# Wrong output from jstl date type

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, jsp, jstl

I am building a project in Spring MVC and I want to include a date picker for the user but the date submitted is always wrong.

Example input - 12/06/2018

Output that I got - 'Wed Feb 12 00:00:00 EET 195' , 'Sat Feb 12 00:00:00 EET 169'

```
     <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="${AttributeNames.DATE}">
       <table align="center" >
        <tr>
            <td><label>Date</label></td>
            <td>
                <form:input type="date" path="date"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
     </form:form>
```

Controller :

```
    @InitBinder
    public void bindingPreparation(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd- 
        yyyy");
        CustomDateEditor orderDateEditor = new 
        CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, orderDateEditor);

    }
      //localhost:8080/project/deadline

    @GetMapping(Mappings.DEADLINE)
    public String getDeadline(Model model){
    log.info("getDeadline called");
    DateModel dateModel = new DateModel();
    model.addAttribute(AttributeNames.DATE, dateModel);
        return ViewNames.DEADLINE;
    }
    @PostMapping(Mappings.DEADLINE)
    public String postDeadLine(@ModelAttribute(AttributeNames.DATE) DateModel dateModel) {
        log.info("postDeadline called with date  = {}", dateModel.getDate().toString());
        bookService.setDeadLine(bookId, dateModel.getDate());
        return "redirect:/" + Mappings.BOOKS;
    }
```

DateModel :

```
  @Data
 public class DateModel {

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy")
private Date date;

public DateModel(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public DateModel(){
    this(null);
}
}

Constants : 
    Mappings.DEADLINE = "deadline"
    ViewNames.DEADLINE = "deadline"
    AttributeNames.DATE = "dateModel"
```

Comment: Are you referring to this line: dateModel.getDate().toString()?

Comment: A date input's value is in ISO format: yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: Are you getting output at console? From the line  `log.info("postDeadline called with date  = {}", dateModel.getDate().toString());` ?

Comment: @JBNizet changed it , works now , lots of thanks!